# Как получить поток из List(а)?

Tags: java, c#

В JAVA можно получить поток из различных объектов, например можно получить поток из List
`list.stream()` чтобы в последствии использовать фильтры и т.п (подробнее тут https://annimon.com/article/2778)

Вопрос, а можно реализовать такое на C#?

Comment: Возможно. В c# это называется linq и работает для IEnumerable и для IQeuryable (читай: как для массивов, списко, словарей и т.п., так и для работы с базой данных). См. тут например введение: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php Т.о. List - это уже поток.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Аналог функции `stream()` не нужен.

В отличие от Java, где коллекции не реализуют базовый интерфейс `Stream<E>`, и его приходится получать при помощи функции `stream()`, в C# коллекции напрямую реализуют аналогичный интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` (то есть как бы сами *являются* stream'ами).

Пример:

Java

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1);
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).filter(n -> n >= 0).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

C#

```cs
List<int> list = new() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1 };
int sum = list.Where(n => n >= 0).Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: Ну, счёт на третью сотню пошёл!

Comment: @AK: Ага, вот так незаметно